# Aptana Studio 3: restore update confirmation dialog and keyboard shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, file-upload, preferences, aptana

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 as a plugin for Eclipse Indigo on Arch Linux x86_64.

I admit I've been using Aptana 2 until yesterday because I can't migrate my custom color schemes automatically, but now I've taken the decision to upgrade anyway and I've come up with 2 questions:
1[solved]) How can I restore the keyboard shortcut to upload a file open in the editor? In Aptana 2 it was CTRL + SHIFT + U, but it no longer works in Aptana 3.
2) How can I restore the FTP upload confirmation dialog *before* the upload? I mean, the dialog that asks "Uploading these files will overwrite those on the server bla bla bla..." or something like that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default eclipse shortcuts by pressing **CTRL+Shift+L** twice.

[Changing eclipse shortcuts](http://www.rossenstoyanchev.org/write/prog/eclipse/eclipse3.html#trying)

Comment: Sorry I should have written that I tried that, but in the Key binds panel, CTRL+SHIFT+U is actually bound to Upload, but it doesn't work: what it does is printing an underlined u (but it's not a shortcut for underlining characters, in fact it doesn't work with the other letters)

Comment: You can try revert back to default settings and make appropriate changes.

Comment: Ooops I've just noticed that this is a system-wide problem, CTRL+SHIFT+u prints an underlined u everywhere O_o It's not related to Eclipse, binding Upload to another combination works... Sorry, question 1) is solved.

Comment: Do you know something about problem 2? Can that dialog be restored?

Comment: Where you are getting this  FTP upload confirmation dialog ?

Comment: It's the opposite problem, I'm not getting it and I want it to display. It was there in Aptana 2: it was the dialog that showed up when trying to upload a file and practically asked for confirmation _before_ uploading the file. Note that it's _not_ the dialog that shows _after_ the upload and confirms that the files have been uploaded: this one shows up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For No. 2, I don't think there is a overwrite warning dialog for FTP upload in either Studio 2 or Studio 3, although there is one for when you drag a file or folder and drop into a remote connection in Studio.  You could add a ticket request at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD.

Comment: I'm perfectly sure it was there in Studio 2, I've used it until yesterday ^^ I've even found a very related request at the tracker you linked: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-294 it says the dialog is there in Aptana 3, but I can't see it....

Comment: Can the fact that I'm using Aptana as an Eclipse plugin be the source of the problem?